# Powershell subclass constructor - Cannot find an overload for "new"

Tags: powershell

**Powershell**: 5.1.1904.1

**OS**: Windows 10 Pro x64, version 2004

I'm probably missing something incredibly obvious here, but...

I have a base class and a subclass.

```
class Vehicle {
    [string]$Name
    Vehicle($Name) {
        $this.Name = $Name
    }
}

class Car : Vehicle {
    [int]$NumWheels
    Car($Name, $NumWheels) {
        $this.NumWheels = $NumWheels
    }
}

$testVar = [Car]::new("Ford Fiesta", 4)
```

When calling the subclass constructor I'm getting the message

> Cannot find an overload for "new" and the argument count: "0".

When I remove the class inheritance I can call the constructor. Powershell seems to find it.

When I *remove* the inheritance and get info on the constructor

```
[Car]::new
```

I see

```
OverloadDefinitions                                   
-------------------                                   
Car new(System.Object Name, System.Object NumWheels)
```

When inheritance is specified (Car : Vehicle) I *still* get

```
OverloadDefinitions                                   
-------------------                                   
Car new(System.Object Name, System.Object NumWheels)
```

Totally unclear why this it seems to see the constructor, but I'm unable to call it when I inherit.

I know I have to be doing something wrong here. :P

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error "no overload with argument count 0" is because there is no default constructor. When you create your own constructor the default constructor is no longer provided for you. The other issue is you are not fulfilling the contract by assigning the name.

Either create a default constructor for `[Vehicle]`

```
class Vehicle {
    [string]$Name
    Vehicle(){}
    Vehicle($Name) {
        $this.Name = $Name
    }
}

class Car : Vehicle {
    [int]$NumWheels

    Car($Name, $NumWheels) {
        $this.NumWheels = $NumWheels
        $this.Name = $Name
    }
}

[Car]::new("Ford Fiesta",4)

NumWheels Name       
--------- ----       
        4 Ford Fiesta
```

or just remove the custom constructor from it

```
class Vehicle {
    [string]$Name
}

class Car : Vehicle {
    [int]$NumWheels

    Car($Name, $NumWheels) {
        $this.NumWheels = $NumWheels
        $this.Name = $Name
    }
}

[Car]::new("Ford Fiesta",4)

NumWheels Name       
--------- ----       
        4 Ford Fiesta
```

Answer (score 6):

To complement [Doug Maurer's helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63912209/45375) answer:

The *ultimate* cause of the problem is that your `Vehicle` class has *no default - always argument-less - constructor*, which, as Doug points out, is the result of the class having at least one *explicitly defined* constructor (`Vehicle($Name) { ... }`). Once you have at least one explicitly defined constructor, you'll have to define an *argument-less* one *explicitly* (`Vehicle() { ... }`) - if needed.

The *immediate* cause is that **the constructor in your *derived* class, `Car`, *implicitly* tries to call an *argument-less* constructor on the base class, `Vehicle`, because you haven't specified an *explicit* base-class constructor call via `base(...)` as part of the derived-class constructor.**

Therefore, **the right solution for you is to call the base-class constructor explicitly, namely the one with the `$Name` parameter**:

```
# Note the call to the base-class constructor via `base`
Car($Name, $NumWheels) : base($Name) {
    $this.NumWheels = $NumWheels
}
```

This obviates the need to add an argument-less constructor to the base class just for the sake of inheritance.

See also: [`about_Classes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes).